# I am getting this error that "The local variable has to be initialized"

Tags: java

here is my source code, I get the error for each of my strings
I am not sure If there is anything else I am missing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RoseBowl {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int programsOrdered;
    double programCost, salesTax, shippingFee, handlingFee, totalCost;
    final double PROGRAM_RATE = 12.95;
    String shippingMethod, groundType, taxExempt, G, S1, N1, P, Y, N2, B, S2, F;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    // user input
    System.out.print ("Enter the number of programs ordered: ");
    programsOrdered = input.nextInt ();

    double programCostForOUTPUT = (PROGRAM_RATE * programsOrdered);

    while(programsOrdered > 0) {


        System.out.print ("Choose shipping method (<G>round, S1(second day), N1(next day), or <P>riority): ");
        shippingMethod = input.next();


        // PROCESS

        // ground shipment
        if (shippingMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("G")) {
            System.out.print("Choose a ground type (<B>ulk), S2(second class), <F>irst class): ");
            groundType = input.next ();

            System.out.print("Select one: <B>ulk, <S>econd Class, <F>irst Class ");
            groundType = input.next();
            // calculate ground shipment
            // FOLLOW THIS PROCESS, RUN IT, IT WORKS FOR JUST GROUND SELECTION AND THEN BULK
            if(groundType.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                shippingFee = 3.00 + (.01 * programCost);
            }

            else if(groundType.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            }// <--if its not b then it is what for other cases?

            else if(groundType.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            }
        }
        // calculate program cost
        programCost = (PROGRAM_RATE * programsOrdered);



        if (shippingMethod == "G" && groundType == "S2") //follow the format above
            shippingFee = (4.00 + (.01 * programCost));
        else if (shippingMethod == G && groundType == F)
            shippingFee = (4.50 + (.01 * programCost));

        // calculate second day shipment
        if (shippingMethod == S1)
            shippingFee = (5.95 + (.02 * programCost));

        // calculate next day shipment
        if (shippingMethod == N1)
            shippingFee = (9.95 + (.03 * programCost));

        // calculate priority shipment
        if (shippingMethod == P)
            shippingFee = (14.95 + (.05 * programCost));

        // calculate handling fees 
        if (shippingFee + programCost < 500)
            handlingFee = 2.50; 
        else if (shippingFee + programCost >= 500)
            handlingFee = 4.50;

        System.out.print("Is the order tax exempt? (<Y>es or N(no): ");
        taxExempt = input.next();

        // calculate tax
        if(taxExempt.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            salesTax = (.0675 * programCost);

        // calculate order total
        totalCost = (programCost + shippingFee + handlingFee + salesTax);

        // OUTPUT

        System.out.printf ("Number of programs ordered: $ %4.2f%s%n" + programsOrdered);
        System.out.printf ("program cost: $ %4.2f%s%n" + programCostForOUTPUT);
        System.out.printf ("Sales tax: $ %4.2f%s%n" + salesTax);
        System.out.printf ("Shipping fee: $ %4.2f%s%n" + shippingFee);
        System.out.printf ("Handling fee: $ %4.2f%s%n" + handlingFee);
        System.out.printf ("Total order amount: $ %4.2f%s" + totalCost);

        // close input
        input.close ();
    } // ending while loop here

}

}   // end main

// end class
```

yeah I must be over looking something small

Comment: Your compiler should tell you which line is giving you problem. Isn't it?

Comment: As a side note: The OCA exam can help you understand your basics of Java

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
double programCost, salesTax, shippingFee, handlingFee, totalCost; // no initial value
...
        if(groundType.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            shippingFee = 3.00 + (.01 * programCost); // accessed here
        }
...
    // calculate program cost
    programCost = (PROGRAM_RATE * programsOrdered); // it is only assigned later
```

you access `programCost` before it is ever initialized. I'm not sure if that's the only error.

You must assign a value to all your local variables before accessing them. Perhaps you should give them default values in their declaration. For example :

```
double programCost = 0.0; // or some other default value that makes sense
```